# Sorting Integer in MySQL-PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, integer

I have a webpage http://skywateryachts.com/disp_new.php where I formatted the currency with no problem.

However, the sorting of the listed price appears to be by order of the first several digits rather than total value. Example, $110,000 appears before $110,900,000 when sorted descending.

The MySQL field type is INT and I just formatted the SELECT statement for the currency symbol.

I'm using the dataviewer extension in the WYSISWYG Webbuilder and custom formatting the code. But I am new to customizing MySQL.

I'm thinking it would be better to eliminate the sort feature and do it myself but would like first to know what the issue could be with the sorting of the digits.

Thanks

Pertinent code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $.fn.alternateRowColors = function()
   {
      $('tbody tr:odd', this).removeClass('even').addClass('odd');
      $('tbody tr:even', this).removeClass('odd').addClass('even');
      return this;
   };
   $('table.sortable').each(function()
   {
      var $dataviewer = $(this);
      $dataviewer.alternateRowColors();
      $('th', $dataviewer).each(function(column)
      {
         var $header = $(this);
         var findSortKey;
         findSortKey = function($cell)
         {
            return $cell.find('.sort-key').text().toUpperCase() + ' ' + $cell.text().toUpperCase();
         };
         if (findSortKey)
         {
            $header.addClass('clickable').hover(function()
            {
               $header.addClass('hover');
            }, function()
            {
               $header.removeClass('hover');
            }).click(function()
            {
               var sortDirection = 1;
               if ($header.is('.sorted-asc'))
               {
                  sortDirection = -1;
               }
               var rows = $dataviewer.find('tbody > tr').get();
               $.each(rows, function(index, row)
               {
                  var $cell = $(row).children('td').eq(column);
                  row.sortKey = findSortKey($cell);
               });
               rows.sort(function(a, b)
               {
                  if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) return -sortDirection;
                  if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) return sortDirection;
                  return 0;
               });
               $.each(rows, function(index, row)
               {
                  $dataviewer.children('tbody').append(row);
                  row.sortKey = null;
               });
               $dataviewer.find('th').removeClass('sorted-asc').removeClass('sorted-desc');
               if (sortDirection == 1)
               {
                  $header.addClass('sorted-asc');
               }
               else
               {
                  $header.addClass('sorted-desc');
               }
               $dataviewer.find('td').removeClass('sorted').filter(':nth-child(' + (column + 1) + ')').addClass('sorted');
               $dataviewer.alternateRowColors();
            });
         }
      });
   });

<div id="dataviewer" style="position:absolute;overflow:auto;left:269px;top:390px;width:803px;height:980px;z-index:46">
<?php
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'xxxx';
$mysql_password = 'xxxx';
$mysql_database = 'xxxx';
$mysql_table = 'boats';
$db = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db);
$sql = "SELECT Date_Listed, Est_DOM, LOA, Builder, Built, Currency, concat('$', format(Listing_Price, 0)), NFS_USA FROM ".$mysql_table;
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
?>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="sortable paginated">
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th>List Date</th>
      <th> Est DOM</th>
      <th> Length</th>
      <th> Builder</th>
      <th> Year Built</th>
      <th> Currency</th>
      <th> Listing Price</th>
      <th> NFS USA</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
   echo "   <tr>\n";
   foreach ($row as $cell)
   {
      echo "      <td>" . $cell . "</td>\n";
   }
   echo "   </tr>\n";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: please show us your query.

Comment: Here it is, and it appears Peter may be on to something. As I said, it is the automated code from the WYSIWYG Webbuilder designer using the dataview extension. Above I added the Sort portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are sorting by your formatted column in the field list of your `SELECT`. Instead, in your `ORDER BY` reference the name of the integer column directly from your table.

So if you have this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(foo, '$99,999,999.99')
FROM bar
ORDER BY 1
```

instead do this

```
SELECT FORMAT(foo, '$99,999,999.99')
FROM bar
ORDER BY foo
```

(Ignore the actual syntax of the formatting - I always have to look that stuff up to get the right function and syntax and I'm just doing it for an example.)